# Read concern "snapshot" and the corresponding clusterTime

Tags: mongodb, transactions, snapshot, acid

There's been a really handy addition in MongoDB 5.x that allows enforcing `snapshot` read concern in some read operations outside transactions and specify the timestamp at which the snapshot is taken via `atClusterTime`. If the timestamp is not provided, `mongo` will select it automatically and kindly return its value to the user for future reference. See:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/read-concern-snapshot/#read-concern-and-atclustertime

Since MongoDB 4.x also supports read concern `snapshot` - but only inside transactions with write concern `majority` - I am wondering if it is also possible to obtain some information about when exactly the snapshot was taken, similarly to what 5.x is doing. I understand that I cannot explicitly specify `atOperationTime` but somehow `mongo` needs to select the timestamp on its own, so it seems reasonable to expect that this information should be available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no convenient way to get the cluster time for Mongo < 5.0. You can always inspect the logs, but I would not consider it a reliable solution. Anyway, here is a possible script you could run on the mongo shell:

```
db.adminCommand( { getLog : "global" } ).log
    .map(x => JSON.parse(x))
    .filter(x => x.c === "TXN")
    .forEach(x => print(JSON.stringify(x.attr.parameters.readConcern)))
```

Let's start by saying that the [`getLog`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/getLog/) command with the `global` filter returns only the most recent logs, so if you are looking for old transactions I guess you need to parse the physical log files. That script:

1. parses the log entries to convert them from strings to JS objects
2. filters the entries and keeps only those related to transactions, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#mongodb-data-TXN) for all the types and additional info
3. retrieves the `readConcern` parameters and print them to console

You should see an output similar to this one:

```
{"level":"snapshot","provenance":"clientSupplied"}
{"level":"snapshot","afterClusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1657483320,"i":1}},"provenance":"clientSupplied"}
{"level":"snapshot","afterClusterTime":{"$timestamp":{"t":1657483977,"i":1}},"provenance":"clientSupplied"}
```

We found the cluster time: `afterClusterTime`.

In the first transaction, I added a document to an empty collection, which could be why it does not show the cluster time (and was not used, of course). I don't know the meaning of each parameter and all the cases in which you will not get the cluster time, but there is good news. To get the logs, if exist, belonging to a given transaction id, you need to apply this filter (instead of the one shown above):

```
.filter(x => x.c === "TXN" && x.attr.parameters.txnNumber === your_txn_id)
```

Comment: I think `afterClusterTime` may not be what we are looking for here. There's a significant difference between `atClusterTime` and the former. This is essentially the value that's provided by corresponding client `session` object as long as causal consistency is enabled. I think it can be accessed via `session.operationTime` assuming one is using `Node.js` driver.

Comment: After I saw the `ClusterTime` in the string I thought I found it, so I am sorry for the misleading answer. Where did you find that `session.operationTime` refers to `afterClusterTime`?

Comment: Unfortunately I had to look into the source code as I was not able to find any relevant information in the documentation, see: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/c9a962f1/src/sessions.ts#L1004